# Calculate the output of volume and surface area of a sphere simple error

Tags: python, geometry, volume

I am new to python. I keep getting the error listed below. Can someone shed some light on the problem I am having? Thanks

volume = 4.0/3.0 * math.pi * (radius*radius*radius)

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

```
import math

radius = input("Enter Radius: ")
print("Radius: " + str(radius))

volume = 4.0/3.0 * math.pi * (radius*radius*radius)
print("Volume: " + str(round(volume,2)))

surface = 4.0 * math.pi * (radius*radius)
print("Surface Area: " + str(round(surface,2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` returns a string. You can't multiply two strings together.

If you want to convert it to an int or float (or any other type), do it like this:

```
radius = float(radius)
```

You may have been confused by looking at example code from Python 2.x, where input called eval() on the string for you, so you got a float or int or list or call to os.system('rm -rf /') or whatever the user typed. This was confusing and dangerous, so they fixed it in 3.0, so now you get just the string, and it's up to you to decide what to do with it.

Comment: Yeah I downloaded the newest python 3.4.1 and the examples I was looking at were 2.x.x so that was not very helpful. But yeah what I did was convert --- radius = float(radius) and I got it working fine. Thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: @user2981423: If you're going to be looking at a lot of 2.x code (and it can be hard to avoid), you may want to skim, and maybe bookmark, [What's New in Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html). Besides the big gotchas that you'll learn really quickly (`print` as a function, Unicode everywhere), there are a bunch of little ones. (However, a few of those changes have since been undone—e.g., `callable` exists again, `u` prefixes on string literals are ignored instead of errors, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your string radius to a float or double.
Try this:

```
import math

radius = input("Enter Radius: ")
print("Radius: " + str(radius))

r = float(radius)

volume = 4.0/3.0 * math.pi * (r*r*r)
print("Volume: " + str(round(volume,2)))

surface = 4.0 * math.pi * (r*r)
print("Surface Area: " + str(round(surface,2)))
```